# Hive with Hadoop vs Hive with spark vs spark sql vs HDFS - How do they all work with each other?

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive, apache-spark-sql, hdfs

I am lil confused which combination should I use to achieve my goal, where I need to store data in HDFS and need to perform analysis based on queried data.

have few queries regarding it:

1. If I use hive with hadoop, then it would use map reduce which is going to slower my queries.(as I am using hadoop HDFS is present here for data storage)
2. Instead of hadoop, If I use spark engine to evaluate my queries, It would be faster but what about HDFS. I will have to create another hadoop cluster to store data in HDFS.
3. If we have spark sql then what is the need of hive ?
4. If I use spark sql then how would it be connecting to HDFS ?

If anyone could explain usage of these tools. 
Thanks !!

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use Hive on Spark. https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Hive+on+Spark
2. You do not need to create another Hadoop cluster. Spark can access data from HDFS.
3. Spark can work with Hive or without Hive.
4. Spark can connect to multiple data sources, including HDFS.